# Yii2 - UrlManager and params with hypens

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-urlmanager

I have the following URLs:

```
http://test.local/index.php?r=site%2Findex&slug=blog-detail
http://test.local/index.php?r=site%2Findex&slug=blog
http://test.local/
```

I want to get:

```
http://test.local/blog
http://test.local/blog-detail
http://test.local/
```

I am sending all requests to `SiteController::actionIndex($slug)`, I am using Basic Application Template.

So far, I have been able to hide `index.php` and `site/index`.

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
       '<slug\w+>' => 'site/index',
    ],
]
```

But it seems `\w+` does not match strings with `-`. Also if slug is empty it should show: `http://test.local/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\w` does not match `-`. You need to use `[\w\-]` instead. And `+` requires at least one char in your case. You should use `*` instead:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
       '<slug:[\w\-]*>' => 'site/index',
    ],
]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer it worked. If I had: base=es&slug=blog/post-slug-slug? I tried to add the slash but it did not catch it, any suggestion?

Comment: I think I found it: [\w_\/-]*

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to make is make specific url based on GET param. With the following example if the user enters url [test.local/Some-nice-article](http://test.local/Some-nice-article) then the `SiteController::actionIndex($slug)` function will get the param.

```
'urlManager' => [
            'pattern' => '<slug>',
            'route' =>'site/index',
            'ecnodeParams' => false,
            //class => any\custom\UrlRuleClass,
            //defaults => [] 
        ]
```

Or you want another url to specify whether it is detailed view? You can do it this way:

```
  'urlManager' => [
                'pattern' => '<slug>-detail',
                'route' =>'site/detail',
                'ecnodeParams' => false,
                //class => any\custom\UrlRuleClass,
                //defaults => [] 
            ]
```

In this example, if the users puts the string '-detail' at the of the slug, then it will parse the route `SiteController::actionDetail($slug)` to the request.

Please note that if you did not yet, enable prettyUrls in the config file

You can find a little more about this topic in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50746730/yii2-routing-with-get-parameters-only-hidden-controller-and-action/50761593#50761593) or in the [Yii2 definitive guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing)